# Class error, Identifier undefined

Tags: c++

In my header file Game I have:

`char *currletters; //the random set of letters`

and in my .cpp file I have:

```
char Game::*getLetters(int x)
{
        char alp[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
                         'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 
                          'o', 'p', 'q','r', 's', 't', 'u', 
                          'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
                        };
        srand(time(NULL));
        int temp = rand() % 25 + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            *currletters = alp[temp];
        }
           return *currletters;
}
```

I am getting an error with `*currletters = alp[temp];` saying that Identifier "currletters" is undefined. I was wondering what the issue could be, I have the header file included as well.

Comment: Only call srand *once*

Comment: @Steephen the input x is how many random words the person wants in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
char Game::*getLetters(int x)
```

to this:

```
char* Game::getLetters(int x)
```

You've got a syntax error in the definition of your class function, so the compiler thinks you're outside the scope of your class, and cannot use that variable.

return statement was added, but is returning the wrong type. `currletters` is of type `char*`, returning a single `char` from a function called `getletters` is misleading.

Suggest returning `currletters` and not `*currletters`

Comment: He corrected his code to include a return statement, you can correct your answer!!